# powershell Deleting all folders except the last three

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, ansible

I have a folder D:/Tests on a Windows machine, it stores folders that are created every day. I need code that runs with ansible on a linux machine that will delete all folders except the last three created ones. I've dug through dozens of articles in stackoverflow, but most of these issues are solved using bat files. For me, this option is not suitable. From what I found, here is the most similar to what I need:

```
Get-Childitem D:\Downloads_D -recurse | where {($_.creationtime -gt $del_date) -and ($_.name -notlike "*dump*" -and $_.name -notlike "*perform*")} | remove-item
```

But my knowledge of Powershell is not enough to edit it so that it performs my task.
Is there any way to achieve my goal using ansible modules, a Windows command line command, or a Powershell command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For powershell, you could do the following:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Downloads_D -Directory | Sort-Object -Property CreationTime | Select-Object -SkipLast 3 | Remove-Item
```

**Explanation**

- Filter directories using `-Directory` from [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1)
- Sort directories by `CreationTime` property using [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.1)
- Skip last 3 directories using [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1) and `-SkipLast 3`. This ensures the 3 most recently created directories are not removed.
- Pipe to [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7.1) to remove the directories

Comment: Thank you very very much! I didn't think it could be solved so easily. However, I moved the "-Recourse " parameter to the end, otherwise the script deletes all the folders in the folder. And added the -Force parameter.
`Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Downloads_D -Directory | Sort-Object -Property CreationTime | Select-Object -SkipLast 3 | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse`
Thank you!